# Prestashop can't find module

Tags: prestashop

i need your help. I can't find module in my prestashop ACP.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Conv.png)

Where can i edit this section? 
Theme: apparel

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this theme, you should login to admin and in module manager search for Hiddentechies static block. Here you will find the testimonial block.
Here is documentation URL - https://www.hiddentechies.com/documentation/prestashop/apparel/#module

Let me know for any issue.